# Why do I only get the hovering annotations of w_players.value?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, bokeh, data-analysis

I'm trying to create an interactive scatterplot with a MultiChoice-widget, which serves as a filter for the datapoints that are going to be displayed. Each datapoint should have hovering annotations with additional information beyond the x-/y-values. The general functionality is already in place, but there is one problem: The hovering annotations only work for datapoints inside 'w_players.value'. How can I fix this, without adding every single datapoint to 'w_players.value' and thus making the whole plot unusable (due to loading times)?

Code + Picture:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas
import panel as pn

## Read and clean the file
data = pd.read_csv('players_stats_by_season_full_details.csv')
data = data[data['League'] == 'NBA']
data = data.dropna()
data = data.reset_index()


w_players = pn.widgets.MultiChoice(name="Player", value = data['Player'].unique().tolist(), options=data['Player'].unique().tolist())

dfi = data.interactive(loc='left')
df_pipeline = dfi.loc[dfi['Player'].isin(w_players)]
df_pipeline.hvplot.scatter(by = 'Player',  x='FGA',y='FGM', hover_cols = ['Player', 'Season', 'FGA', 'FGM'])
```

[This is how it looks. Notice that only datapoints of "Stephen Curry" have hovering Annotations, although I'm also hovering over datapoints of "Kevin Durant"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPYS.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I'm easily able to hover over either 2 player data points and get the annotations. Also, your pic doesn't display what you are saying. It's just a static image.

Comment: @chitown88 Sorry, the code is probably a little misleading. The code is supposed to show the "fix" I mentioned during my explanation, where I just add every single player to 'w_players.value'. While this does fix the issue with missing hovering annotations, it also (as you might have seen) leads to absurd loading times (during the creation of the plot AND updates via widget) and to every single data point being shown from the start. The latter can be somewhat fixed with the addition of another widget, which empties w_player.values, but there has to be a smoother and more efficient solution.

Comment: ah gotcha. However, I don't notice the loading times since I'm not using your dataset.

Comment: @chitown88 All good. Have you ever created a similar visualization that worked efficiently and you are willing to share? Or do you have any idea on how to improve it?

Comment: I’ll look into it. Is it possible for you ti share your dataset to test on?

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks a lot. Here is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jacobbaruch/basketball-players-stats-per-season-49-leagues